# True long int fields in a File Geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-10.1, file-geodatabase, feature-class

I have been wondering about the 'long ints' in FGDBs. They are 32 bit, which is just a regular int in most places. Is it possible to actually have a field be a 64 bit int?

I have some bigint's (64 bit) in a PostGIS database that I am translating into a FGDB with ogr2ogr and they all max out in long ints (2,147,483,647) in the FGDB. I know I can cast them as text and it will get the numbers in there, but that makes it harder to deal with them as numbers. I played with the doubles a little bit, but they start to go into scientific notation once they are too large, which is also not useful.

Comment: Scientific notation is just a way of printing out the values. It is independent of how they are actually stored and can be controlled in most software by formatting options.  Doubles store ints to 51 bits precision (up to 2,251,799,813,685,247), which is more than is needed for almost any practical application.

Comment: I actually noticed that you can type in about 14 or 15 digits when editing a double field it no long stays the original number, it may just be the way Arc is displaying it, but it is hard to look at the numbers in scientific notation when they should just be a int (no decimals) anyways. It also means casting the numbers away from their original types, which is what I was hoping to avoid. If I have to I can cast it away to text like I do now, but it would be a lot nicer to keep them as numbers.